# How to set "useGravity" for Rigidbody to entities in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

For the position you can use this:
`[Inject] private ComponentDataFromEntity<Position> _position;`

But cant use it for Rigidbody. How to access the parameters for Rigidbody for entities?